# How many questions are asked daily on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I really like the idea of Stack Overflow, but I wonder if anyone knows (maybe the site admins, if they're reading) how many new questions are being asked each day.

Is it around 5,000?
200,000?
A million?

Comment: Here's a good start: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dump

Comment: A million? I don't think so.

Comment: If it was possible to migrate this to Meta SO, that'd be great.

Comment: @dorukayhan: It's not. 60 days is the limit, period.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the day of the week. Recently it's around 10,000 from Monday to Friday and around 4,500 on weekends:

[image: Stack Overflow Stats - number of questions per day over last 30 days]

You can find current values on https://sostats.github.io - it's a website presenting the latest statistics about Stack Overflow (questions, answers, comments and users). It's fed with data retrieved from the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way of retrieving this figure (*also for other sites than Stack Overflow*) is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/520226/657753/#graph). Note that the data is refreshed only once a week, on Sunday, so it does not give real-time results. The query could be extended to include only questions with a certain tag, if you like.

[image]

Comment: Here you can also notice how questions get deleted over time.

Answer (score 2):

Per the page https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions in January 2018 Stack Overflow receives about 6,900 new questions per day, about 5 per minute.

Answer (score 2):

The API [stats](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/stats) route has an entry that shows how many questions a site gets every minute:

> ```
>  "questions_per_minute": 3.07,
> ```

So, around 4421/day as of this post